# Как вычислить сумму чисел 1/(1*2) - 1/(2*3) + 1/(3*4) + . + (-1)^(n+1) / (n * (n + 1), где n > 0

Tags: c#

Пожалуйста помогите с программой для  вычисления суммы чисел `1/(1*2) - 1/(2*3) + 1/(3*4) + ... + (-1)^(n+1) / (n * (n + 1))`, где n > 0
Без использования условных конструкций , тернарного оператора ? и метода Math.Pow().
в задании есть юнит тесты , тот вариант что я написал не проходит , понял что ряд должен менять знак в зависимости от четности числа но как это реализовать по другому ?
P.S. плиз не судите строго я только обучаюсь

```
 public static double GetSum(int n)
    {
        double result = 0;
        double sign = 1;
        for (double i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            result += sign * (1 / i * (i + 1));
            sign = -sign;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаменатель нужно целиком в скобки взять, без скобок не делит, а домножает на `i + 1`:

```
result += sign / (i * (i + 1));
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек , мда уж тупанул , причина моих многочасовых мучений была в скобке  , заработало